# Facebook App Login: Is it possible to catch 'cancelButtonPressed' event?

Tags: event-handling, authorization, facebook-ios-sdk

Is it possible to catch event **'CancelButtonPressed'** in `Facebook App` through `facebook-ios-sdk` authorization flow?

I use pretty old version of `Facebook SDK for IOS` and open session like this:

```
[_facebookSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView
                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"this is FBSession State: %d",status);
                NSLog(@"this is NSError: %@",error);
                NSLog(@"create new session with permissions: %@",_facebookSession.permissions);
            }];
```

I saw [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12684428/how-to-return-to-app-if-user-cancel-facebook-login) question, but maybe something changed in `Facebook IOS SDK`?

Maybe somebody knows answer or good solution?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**

```
if ([_facebookSession state]==FBSessionStateCreatedOpening){
    // if we call FBApp, facebook session will be in this state (createdOpening)
    // and we need to check it and close, to recall FBApp
    [_facebookSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    // and now recrate session and open it ;)
    _facebookSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:kAppId
                                                    permissions:permissions
                                                urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                                             tokenCacheStrategy:[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy defaultInstance]
                                ];

    //and reopen it like `[_facebookSession openWith... ];`
}
```

Comment: I find only one way: 

kill session, when i reentered in these peace of code. See my edit